# Li-Polymer Charge cycle

Tags: charging

The Li-Ion battery has 4 stages of charging :the initial trickle-charging to bring battery to Pre-charge stage, then constant current charging, then constant voltage charging(its like floating....right?) & final stage Top-up charge" .
Can anyone reply with the stages of charging for Li-Polymer ( iPhone use Li-Polymer), or suggest some link which explains about Li-polymer charging details.

Answer (score 1):

the answer for your question is present in this 
page:http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

Comment: It's better to put some detail in your answer rather than just a link so it's useful if the link goes dead, even if you just say it makes no difference to the charger and give the link as a reference.

Comment: sure will do it!!